# Downloading image files from Google Drive using R

Tags: r, google-sheets, tidyverse, google-forms

I created a Google Form that I use for entering data in the field. Several of the fields in the Google Form require taking a photo. In this case, it is a photograph of a bird that we have captured from different angles (tail, back, front, etc).

I'm wondering if it is possible to download those images by reading the Google Form responses into R.

Here's what the Google Form responses look like in Google Sheet form:

```
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tribble(
  ~birdID, ~date, ~tailphoto,
189307134, '2019-01-15', 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SfmmmYTahcmwGnyCFuXoecn_ofXpagAr',
189307135, '2019-01-13', 'https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e4FGSK6jaLPyeu_TFGPXxSZAcv3obQMd'
)


# A tibble: 2 x 3
     birdID date       tailphoto                                                         
      <dbl> <chr>      <chr>                                                             
1 189307134 2019-01-15 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1SfmmmYTahcmwGnyCFuXoecn_ofXpagAr
2 189307135 2019-01-13 https://drive.google.com/open?id=1e4FGSK6jaLPyeu_TFGPXxSZAcv3obQMd
```

So the question is how to download the images using the Google Drive link in each photo column. Ideally, I'd like to name each photo by the band number (bird ID), date, and photo type, like so:

189307145_2019-01-15_tail.jpg

If I have the file name I can just do this to at least download the photo:

```
library(googledrive)

image = 'IMG_20190114_090554.jpg'

drive_download(file = image, path = 'bird.jpg')
```

The issue though is that there doesn't appear to be a way to link a drive link and its corresponding file name...

Comment: This link provided an answer for how to download the images from Google Drive. Basically the first part of the link above needs to look like this for exporting:

`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=`

So you can just chop off the first bit of the link above and replace with that, then download the image using the 'curl' library:

`curl_download(url = 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=1kra8bSf4WMpoK8BTyFip2OxmUuz30Thl', 
              destfile = 'bird.jpg')`

Comment: I think other people would benefit from this comment. Consider converting your comment to an answer or add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of approaching my question:

```
# first part of link needs to look like this for downloading
 export <- 'https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id='

# convert all sharing links to downloading links by 1) chopping off photo ID at end of link,
# and 2) adding the export format in front of the photo ID
dat <- dat %>%
  mutate_at(vars(tailphoto), ~str_sub(., start = -33, end = -1)) %>%
  mutate_at(vars(tailphoto), ~paste0(export, .)) 
dat
```

I used `mutate_at` because in my original dataset I have multiple photo types. You could then use `curl_download` to download each image in a loop.